# undeclared identifier - unsure as to why

Tags: c, undeclared-identifier

I am just learning C

I have written the following:

```
void main(void)
{
    unsigned int  curr_dat = 0; // The current dat file to use
    unsigned char ch = 0;       // Key entered at keyboard
    unsigned char lastkey = 0;  // Last key entered (movement command)
    FILE *fp;
}
```

However i am getting these errors when trying to compile:
`error C2065: 'FILE' : undeclared identifier`
`error C2065: 'fp' : undeclared identifier`
`warning C4552: '*' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect`

I'm unsure why as i believe `FILE` is a valid identifier in C

I am using Developer Command Prompt for VS2012 to compile

Comment: And  `int main` instead of `void main`

Comment: Thanks @FredLarson, that worked. Had no idea. 
Why int @AlterMann?

Comment: Because the standard says so ;)

Comment: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Comment: Interesting, i'll give that a read. Thanks

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <stdio.h>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`FILE` is declared in `stdio.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io). Add `#include <stdio.h>` to the top of your file.

Answer (score 3):

`FILE` is type from `stdio.h`. To use it you have to add:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

at the top of your file. The result can be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void) {
    unsigned int  curr_dat = 0; // The current dat file to use
    unsigned char ch = 0;       // Key entered at keyboard
    unsigned char lastkey = 0;  // Last key entered (movement command)
    FILE *fp;
}
```